# TodoMVC with angular-typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, todomvc

I am learning Typescript and Angular and I just fixed a problem with an unregistered controller because the script for the controller was loaded after the script for the application module.  So I looked at index.html in the TodoMVC sample to see how the files for the controller, service and directives were loaded and don't see them loaded anywhere.  Where does the code for these classes get loaded?

Comment: A link to the TodoMVC sample you referring to might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are loaded using script tags : https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/architecture-examples/angularjs/index.html#L69-L73